# MS Office Javascript API

Tags: javascript, ms-office

I'm still fairly new to programming in general, but my current objective is creating web apps to run inside of Excel using the Office JS framework. Since I'm still kind of at a beginner level, I'm finding it hard to locate resources to learn this framework. Most of what I'm finding are code snippets etc. Is this just the sad reality of the intermediate level, no more hand holding tutorials? I'm fine with that, but I feel like there isn't a lot of documentation out there that outlines methods specific to the office API. If there is someone out there that either can provide some resources I could learn from, or who could answer specific questions as I struggle my way through it, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of informations on this API here :
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/master/excel